# Why does my xcodeproj directory appear as a file and how do I stop it from doing that?

Tags: xcode, macos

According to my subversion client and the command line, my xcodeproj file is actually a directory. However, trying to list the content of it from other applications such as my merge tool, it appears only as a file and prevents me from accessing the files contained within it?

What is the point of all this, where is the magic that makes it happen and how can I access the files in that directory from normal applications?

Answer (score 0):

It is a bundle, and you can navigate into via command line or by right clicking and selecting show contents ... If you want it to never work as a bundle then you will have to remove that property, which I think is an extended attribute... So you will need to check out xargs.

Comment: I can list the content the way you describe in Finder, but it doesn't let me select files within the directory from my merge tool...

Comment: which tool? if file merge check out opendiff

Comment: I don't know anything about it... but looking at the man page online it looks like it can be launched from the command line, the command line doesn't differentiate between bundles... something else you could do, would be make an alias to the bundles contents directory.

Comment: Launching tools from the command line may work but in general I still don't have a way of accessing the content from UI applications. If by alias you mean a symbolic link, then no, this did not work - it still shows up as a single file, not a directory.

Comment: aliases are different from symbolic links, there isn't really a perfect analogy... they work in some ways like symbolic links, but the finder is more aware of them... I just verified that in safari I can follow aliases... so of you make an alias to a the Contents dir inside of a bundle, you can follow that...